# Google Drive Access: At least one client secrets (Installed or Web) should be set

Tags: asp.net, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

We have tested demo code of Google Drive (for console application) and that went correct, after that we are trying to implement the same to Web Application which at present is hosted at localhost. The application is giving us this exception:

> *An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Google.Apis.Auth.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: At least one client secrets (Installed or Web) should be
>   set*

The code we are trying to run is this:

```
UserCredential credential;
        GoogleClientSecrets s= new GoogleClientSecrets();
        s.Secrets.ClientId="xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
        s.Secrets.ClientSecret="yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";
        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(s.Secrets,Scopes,"user",CancellationToken.None,null).Result;
        var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential
            //ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });
```

Before this we have put refresh token to get access token. We are also not aware what to do with this access token stores in a string variable.

We are trying to have it accessed unattanded, we used google playground to get first refresh token.

Please help us out, we are trying to get it done from last 7 days with no success.

Comment: this might get you started.  http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-authentication-c/  The client library will handle storing the refreshtoken for you you don't need to deal with that.  In production you really shouldn't be using playground  to generate your refresh tokens you should be doing this with your code.

Comment: I would like users to connect and be able to access and manipulate my google drive. Do I need service account? I also learned that service account need Google Apps for Business or something its kind, is it correct?

Comment: Yes you should use a service account and not Oauth2.   I don't know anything about apps for business so cant tell you about that.

Comment: The code with service account have gone through perfectly but it shows only one item in files object which is like that: 
Title: Getting started ID: 0B57_skgqgLwTc3RhcnRlcl9maWxl whereas I have many files in my google Drive

Comment: A service account isn't you it is a dummy user.  Take the Service account email address and give it permissions to a folder on your personal drive account it will be able to see it.

Comment: "you really shouldn't be using playground to generate your refresh tokens you should be doing this with your code". Simply not true. A refresh token is a refresh token. It matters not how it was created since it will be saved to some local file and subsequently retrieved from there before being used. OP says "We are trying to have it accessed unattended" which is precisely the use case that stored refresh tokens was designed for.

Comment: @daimto made me very easy to achieve the same. Service account works like a charm for me. Still I feel some discomfort to this like what if I would like some people to restrict to few directory or files?

Comment: Apart from this @pinoyyid appreciate if you could demonstrate any code to do with refresh token. I have wasted a week in this but still to achieve.

Comment: @pinoyyid do you need a refreshToken with a service account? Are services accounts used for unattended access?

Comment: @YogeshAswani Sorry, I don't use the c# library . There will be some class/method that allows you to instantiate a refresh token into a credential. You'll just need to read the docs or ask a specific question "how do I set a previously saved refresh token in the google c3 oauth lib?"

Comment: @DaImTo from the Google docs "In some cases, your application might need to access a Google API when the user is not present. " and the OP asked "We are trying to have it accessed unattanded". It doesn't get any better a fit than that. imho using an additional account as a proxy is a kludge and is NOT what service accounts are intended for - "a service account, which is an account that belongs to your application instead of to an individual end user". By relying on an additional account, and the vagaries of Drive sharing, there are more moving parts. At the end of the day, both solutions work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Code for a service account:**

```
string[] scopes = new string[] {DriveService.Scope.Drive}; // Full access
var keyFilePath = @"c:\file.p12" ;    // Downloaded from https://console.developers.google.com 
var serviceAccountEmail = "xx@developer.gserviceaccount.com";  // found https://console.developers.google.com 


//loading the Key file 
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable); 
var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential( new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail) { 
Scopes = scopes}.FromCertificate(certificate));
```

code ripped from [Google Drive Authentication C#](http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-authentication-c/) which also incudes an example for using Oauth2

**Upload file**

```
/// <summary>
        /// Uploads a file
        /// Documentation: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="_service">a Valid authenticated DriveService</param>
        /// <param name="_uploadFile">path to the file to upload</param>
        /// <param name="_parent">Collection of parent folders which contain this file. 
        ///                       Setting this field will put the file in all of the provided folders. root folder.</param>
        /// <returns>If upload succeeded returns the File resource of the uploaded file 
        ///          If the upload fails returns null</returns>
        public static File uploadFile(DriveService _service, string _uploadFile, string _parent) {

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(_uploadFile))
            {
                File body = new File();
                body.Title = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(_uploadFile);
                body.Description = "File uploaded by Diamto Drive Sample";
                body.MimeType = GetMimeType(_uploadFile);
                body.Parents = new List<ParentReference>() { new ParentReference() { Id = _parent } };

                // File's content.
                byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(_uploadFile);
                System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);
                try
                {
                    FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = _service.Files.Insert(body, stream, GetMimeType(_uploadFile));
                    //request.Convert = true;   // uncomment this line if you want files to be converted to Drive format
                    request.Upload();
                    return request.ResponseBody;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
                    return null;
                }
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine("File does not exist: " + _uploadFile);
                return null;
            }           

        }
```

Code ripped from [DaimtoGoogleDriveHelper.cs](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/blob/master/Google-Drive/Google-Drive-Api-dotnet/Google-Drive-Api-dotnet/DaimtoGoogleDriveHelper.cs)

**Tip:**

The thing to remember with a service account is that it is not you, it is a dummy user account.  A service account has its own google drive account so uploading files to it will upload to its account not yours.   What you can do is take the service account email address add it as a user on a folder in YOUR personal google drive account giving it write access.  This will then allow the Service account to upload a file to your personal google drive account.  Remember to patch the file after upload granting yourself permissions to the file other wise the owner of the file will be the service account.  There is currently a bug in the Google Drive api you have to patch the permissions on the file after you upload the file you cant do it at the time you upload it its a two step process.  (been there done that)

Google drive sample project can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/master/Google-Drive)

Comment: "Remember to patch the file after upload granting yourself permissions to the file other wise the owner of the file will be the service account. ", how can we do it in c#